# blur does not work in custom editable cell

Tags: jquery

I am using DataTables.Net plug-in for jQuery and I to want add custom inline edit solution. I know there is Editable plug-in but it is not free.

I started with following on click event action

```
// Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell

$('#table1').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
    editCell(this);
} );
```

which calls editCell function which makes cell editable

```
function editCell(HTMLTableCellElement) {
    // Check if selected cell is not in edit mode
    if ($(HTMLTableCellElement).hasClass('rowEditable') == false) {
        // Mark cell to edit mode
        $(HTMLTableCellElement).addClass('rowEditable');
        // Make editable
        $(HTMLTableCellElement).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(HTMLTableCellElement).html() + '">');
        // Trigger when cell loose focus
        $(HTMLTableCellElement).blur(function () {
            alert("Record is saving");
            $(HTMLTableCellElement).html($(HTMLTableCellElement).find("input").val());
            $(HTMLTableCellElement).removeClass('rowEditable');
        });
    }
}
```

but I have a **problem** that `alert("Record is saving");` is never called.

EDIT: How Gene R noticed, i needed to Blur input and not a cell itself
. Solution is to change this line

```
$(HTMLTableCellElement).blur(function ()
```

To this

```
// Focus the cell input
// alert("Record is saving");
$(HTMLTableCellElement).find('input').focus();
$(HTMLTableCellElement).find('input').blur(function ()
```

Comment: put your blur event to input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `HTMLTableCellElement` is a `td`, which doesn't have a `blur` event. Moreover, when you are changing the code to what you have shown, you also need to change the event handling.

And in the second way, you are actually defining the `blur` event and not calling it. You should have defined the `blur` event even before you put this line:

```
$(HTMLTableCellElement).find('input').blur(function ()
```

And instead of the above line, use this:

```
$(HTMLTableCellElement).find('input').trigger("blur");
```

Comment: the problem was I didn't have $(HTMLTableCellElement).removeClass('rowEditable'); there and it is working now but I will look to your solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I built my own plugin that does this that is very configurable and super quick to implement.

Here's the git repo: [DataTables CellEdit Plugin](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit)

And here's my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36266167/1159067) with a quick example: